# expanding each row in a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

Consider this simple example

```
data = pd.DataFrame({'mydate' : [pd.to_datetime('2016-06-06'),
                                 pd.to_datetime('2016-06-02')],
                     'value' : [1, 2]})

data.set_index('mydate', inplace = True)

data
Out[260]: 
            value
mydate           
2016-06-06      1
2016-06-02      2
```

I want to iterate over each row so that the dataframe gets "enlarged" by a couple days (2 days before, 2 days after) around each index value (which is  a date) for the current row.

For instance, if you consider the first row, I want to tell Pandas to add 4 more rows, corresponding to the days `2016-06-04`, `2016-06-05`, `2016-06-07` and `2016-06-07`. The `value` for these extra rows can just be whathever is in `value` for that row (in this case: 1). This logic is applied every row and the final dataframe is the concatenation of all these enlarged dataframes.

I have tried the following function in an `apply(., axis = 1)` :

```
def expand_onerow(df, ndaysback = 2, nhdaysfwd = 2):

    new_index = pd.date_range(pd.to_datetime(df.name) - pd.Timedelta(days=ndaysback), 
                              pd.to_datetime(df.name) + pd.Timedelta(days=nhdaysfwd), 
                              freq='D')

    newdf = df.reindex(index=new_index, method='nearest')     #New df with expanded index
    return newdf
```

But unfortunately I running
 `data.apply(lambda x: expand_onerow(x), axis = 1)`
gives:

```
  File "pandas/_libs/tslib.pyx", line 1165, in pandas._libs.tslib._Timestamp.__richcmp__

TypeError: ("Cannot compare type 'Timestamp' with type 'str'", 'occurred at index 2016-06-06 00:00:00')
```

Another approach I tried is the following: I first reset the index,

```
data.reset_index(inplace = True)
data
Out[339]: 
      mydate  value
0 2016-06-06      1
1 2016-06-02      2
```

Then I use a slight modification of my function

```
def expand_onerow_alt(df, ndaysback = 2, nhdaysfwd = 2):

    new_index = pd.date_range(pd.to_datetime(df.mydate) - pd.Timedelta(days=ndaysback), 
                              pd.to_datetime(df.mydate) + pd.Timedelta(days=nhdaysfwd), 
                              freq='D')
    newdf = pd.Series(df).reindex(index = new_index).T  #New df with expanded index
    return newdf
```

which gives

```
data.apply(lambda x: expand_onerow_alt(x), axis = 1)
Out[338]: 
   2016-05-31  2016-06-01  2016-06-02  2016-06-03  2016-06-04  2016-06-05  2016-06-06  2016-06-07  2016-06-08
0         nan         nan         nan         nan         nan         nan         nan         nan         nan
1         nan         nan         nan         nan         nan         nan         nan         nan         nan
```

closer but not there yet...

I do not understand what is wrong here. What am I missing? I am looking for the most Pandonic approach here.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I modify little bit of your function

```
def expand_onerow(df, ndaysback = 2, nhdaysfwd = 2):

    new_index = pd.date_range(pd.to_datetime(df.index[0]) - pd.Timedelta(days=ndaysback),
                              pd.to_datetime(df.index[0]) + pd.Timedelta(days=nhdaysfwd),
                              freq='D')

    newdf = df.reindex(index=new_index, method='nearest')     #New df with expanded index
    return newdf

pd.concat([expand_onerow(data.loc[[x],:], ndaysback = 2, nhdaysfwd = 2) for x ,_ in data.iterrows()])


Out[455]: 
            value
2016-05-31      2
2016-06-01      2
2016-06-02      2
2016-06-03      2
2016-06-04      2
2016-06-04      1
2016-06-05      1
2016-06-06      1
2016-06-07      1
2016-06-08      1
```

More info

Basically that one line equal to

```
l=[]
for x ,_ in data.iterrows():

    l.append(expand_onerow(data.loc[[x],:], ndaysback = 2, nhdaysfwd = 2))# query out each row by using their index(x is the index for each row) and append then into a empty list


pd.concat(l)# concat the list to one df at the end
```

Comment: thanks wen but why does my `apply` does not work here? Apply should take care of the `concat` directly. Also, I am not sure the `groupby` is correct here. I want to apply `expand_onerow` to every single index date - even if there are duplicates

Comment: @ℕʘʘḆḽḘ then we change to iterrows : -)

Comment: @ℕʘʘḆḽḘ change to `pd.concat([expand_onerow(data.iloc[[x],:], ndaysback = 2, nhdaysfwd = 2) for x in list(range(len(data)))])
`

Comment: thanks but that looks a bit black-boxy dont you think :) why cant I have it work with an apply??? :(

Comment: @ℕʘʘḆḽḘ I think when we do apply it will not carry over the dataframe format for each row, which will make the reindex does not work

Comment: I see. but you proposed an idea with `iterrows`. I find that more pandonic. can you get it to work?

Comment: @ℕʘʘḆḽḘ sure `pd.concat([expand_onerow(data.loc[[x],:], ndaysback = 2, nhdaysfwd = 2) for x ,_ in data.iterrows()])`

Comment: pretty cool! I didnt know the syntax `x, _`. what does the `_` means here? can you perhars use this solution and explain step by step what it does?

Comment: @ℕʘʘḆḽḘ _, means we do not need that output for each loop, will add some explanation

Comment: thanks! but what happens if you omit the `_` ? would that work with iterrtuples as well (which seems to be faster)?

Comment: also, I think you should update your question because the first part of it refers to the old solution. just trying to make a good example of a nice question with a nice clean answer as well :) thanks!!