# how to speed up a reindex at the row level?

Tags: python, pandas

Consider the following example

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

myidx = pd.date_range('2016-01-01','2017-01-01')
data = pd.DataFrame({'value' : xrange(len(myidx))}, index = myidx)

data.head()
Out[16]: 
            value
2016-01-01      0
2016-01-02      1
2016-01-03      2
2016-01-04      3
2016-01-05      4
```

This problem is related to [expanding each row in a dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49036714/expanding-each-row-in-a-dataframe)

I absolutely need to improve the performance of something that is intuitively very simple: I need to "enlarge" the dataframe so that each index value gets "enlarged" by a couple days (2 days before, 2 days after).

To do this task, I have the following function

```
def expand_onerow(df, ndaysback = 2, nhdaysfwd = 2):
    new_index = pd.date_range(pd.to_datetime(df.index[0]) - pd.Timedelta(days=ndaysback),
                              pd.to_datetime(df.index[0]) + pd.Timedelta(days=nhdaysfwd),
                              freq='D')
    newdf = df.reindex(index=new_index, method='nearest')     #New df with expanded index
    return newdf
```

Now either using `iterrows` or the (supposedly) faster `itertuples` gives poor results.

```
%timeit pd.concat([expand_onerow(data.loc[[x],:], ndaysback = 2, nhdaysfwd = 2) for x ,_ in data.iterrows()])
1 loop, best of 3: 574 ms per loop

%timeit pd.concat([expand_onerow(data.loc[[x.Index],:], ndaysback = 2, nhdaysfwd = 2) for x in data.itertuples()])
1 loop, best of 3: 643 ms per loop
```

Any ideas how to speed up the generation of final dataframe? I have millions of obs in my real dataframe, and the index dates are not necessarily consecutive as they are in this example.

`head(10)` on the final dataframe

```
Out[21]: 
            value
2015-12-30      0
2015-12-31      0
2016-01-01      0
2016-01-02      0
2016-01-03      0
2015-12-31      1
2016-01-01      1
2016-01-02      1
2016-01-03      1
2016-01-04      1
```

Thanks!

Comment: Is the order of the rows important?

Comment: what do you mean? as long as each `value` is propagated correctly to the corresponding (re-)index I dont care :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When using NumPy/Pandas, the key to speed is often applying vectorized functions to the largest arrays/NDFrames possible. The main reason why your original code is slow is because it calls `expand_onerow` once *for each row*. The rows are tiny and you have millions of them. To make it faster, we need to find a way to express the calculation in terms of functions applied to whole DataFrames or at least whole columns. This tends to achieve the result with more time having been spent in fast C or Fortran code and less time in slower Python code.

In this case, the result can be obtained by making copies of `data` and shifting the index *of the whole DataFrame* by `i` days:

```
new = df.copy()
new.index = df.index + pd.Timedelta(days=i)
dfs.append(new)
```

and then concatenating the shifted copies:

```
pd.concat(dfs)
```

---

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

myidx = pd.date_range('2016-01-01','2017-01-01')
data = pd.DataFrame({'value' : range(len(myidx))}, index = myidx)


def expand_onerow(df, ndaysback = 2, nhdaysfwd = 2):
    new_index = pd.date_range(pd.to_datetime(df.index[0]) - pd.Timedelta(days=ndaysback),
                              pd.to_datetime(df.index[0]) + pd.Timedelta(days=nhdaysfwd),
                              freq='D')
    newdf = df.reindex(index=new_index, method='nearest')     #New df with expanded index
    return newdf

def orig(df, ndaysback=2, ndaysfwd=2):
    return pd.concat([expand_onerow(data.loc[[x],:], ndaysback = ndaysback, nhdaysfwd = ndaysfwd) for x ,_ in data.iterrows()])

def alt(df, ndaysback=2, ndaysfwd=2):
    dfs = [df]
    for i in range(-ndaysback, ndaysfwd+1):
        if i != 0:
            new = df.copy()
            new.index = df.index + pd.Timedelta(days=i)
            # you could instead use
            # new = df.set_index(df.index + pd.Timedelta(days=i))
            # but it made the timeit result a bit slower
            dfs.append(new)
    return pd.concat(dfs)
```

Notice that `alt` has a Python loop with (essentially) 4 iterations. `orig` has a Python loop (in the form of a list comprehension) with `len(df)` iterations. Making fewer function calls and applying vectorized functions to bigger array-like objects is how `alt` gains speed over `orig`.

---

Here is a benchmark comparing `orig` and `alt` on `data`:

```
In [40]: %timeit orig(data)
1 loop, best of 3: 1.15 s per loop

In [76]: %timeit alt(data)
100 loops, best of 3: 2.22 ms per loop

In [77]: 1150/2.22
Out[77]: 518.018018018018
```

So `alt` is over 500x faster than `orig` on a 367-row DataFrame. For small-to-medium sized DataFrame, the speed advantage tends to grow as `len(data)` gets larger, because `alt`'s Python loop will still have 4 iterations, while `orig`'s loop gets longer. At some point however, for really large DataFrames, I would expect the speed advantage to crest at some constant factor -- I don't know how large it would be, except that it should be greater than 500x.

---

This checks that the two functions, `orig` and `alt` produce the same result (but in a different order):

```
result = alt(data)
expected = orig(data)
result = result.reset_index().sort_values(by=['index','value']).reset_index(drop=True)
expected = expected.reset_index().sort_values(by=['index','value']).reset_index(drop=True)
assert expected.equals(result)
```

Comment: well, I have too say this is a *decent* increase in speed :) thanks master unutbu :)

Comment: @unutbu, nice examples. But I'm not sure the `alt` speedup over `orig` comes from much less memory copy/moving, or from more vectorized operations?